# Error in installing Virtualbox guest additions iso file mount

Tags: virtualbox, guest-additions

I have install Virtualbox 4.0.4-OSE on my Ubuntu 11.04.
I want to install the guest additions of Virtualbox. but I've gotten this error:

```
 Failed to open the CD/DVD image /home/bigbang/.VirtualBox/VBoxGuestAdditions_4.0.4.iso.
 The medium '/home/bigbang/.VirtualBox/VBoxGuestAdditions_4.0.4.iso' can't be used as the requested device type.
```

The step I do for install it is:

Devices > Install Guest Additions , then click yes to download the required .iso file from the internet and then click mount button after the file is downloaded and then it gives me the error.

Edited: My host is Ubuntu and the guest os is XP.

Comment: My host is Ubuntu and the guest os is XP.

Comment: Add that to the question it self please, use the edit button bellow it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To mount and use guest additions you first have to make sure `virtualbox-guest-additions` is installed and ready to use.  Pop into terminal and type:

```
sudo apt-get install virtualbox-guest-additions
```

For recent versions of ubuntu (e.g. 13.10), its

```
sudo apt-get install virtualbox-guest-additions-iso
```